# Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 Radeon HD 5770 but basic display functionality does not work

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, radeon

Lets start by saying that i wish I had read this before and I wish that on an upgrade prompt Ubuntu would warn about major compatibility issues such as - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

however based on this page - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver
my gpu should work just fine with the 16.04 drivers

So, I have just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and my two screens are not detected and mirroring instead of extending the desktop.

```
$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 400, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024      0.00* 
   1280x960       0.00  
   1152x864       0.00  
   1024x768       0.00  
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00  
   720x400        0.00
```

Also the resolution is too low and monitor instead of the two connected are detected as **default**. On IRC #ubuntu I have got the suggestion to configure xorg and looking at the guide at http://zeroset.mnim.org/2013/01/07/dual-head-monitor-setup-on-ubuntu-linux-with-xorg-and-radeon/ I see that `xrandr` is supposed to detect the monitors well to attempt a Xorg config.

From Xorg log - **Segmentation fault**

```
[  5786.223] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  5786.223] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[  5786.223] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[  5786.223] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[  5786.223] (II) [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[  5786.223] (EE) 
[  5786.223] (EE) Backtrace:
[  5786.223] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x5581fdedc5ce]
[  5786.223] (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5581fdd2a000+0x1b6959) [0x5581fdee0959]
[  5786.223] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7fcc5f18c000+0x354a0) [0x7fcc5f1c14a0]
[  5786.223] (EE) 
[  5786.223] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[  5786.223] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  5786.223] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[  5786.223] (EE) 
[  5786.223] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
```

I dont need 3D acceleration and would like to fix the problem instead of downgrading to 14.04. What else can I try?

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was not a problem with compatibility between drivers/cards and kernel. I had nomodeset in my grub config blocking radeon driver from loading.

to check grub config see this article - [how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/](http://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/)

So in my experience after looking at this problem try the following

check modprobe config to make sure the correct driver is blacklisted/or not,under /etc/modprobe.d/ files and make sure radeon is not blacklisted

check grub as described above and remove the nomodeset option bearing in mind that this might cause other problems

Comment: This worked for me as well. Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

I was in the exact same position with both my monitors mirroring each other.  Thanks to Bizmate, I checked under etc/modprobe.d, and I found a file called "fglrx-core.conf".

The contents of "fglrx-core.conf" were as follows:

> # This file was installed by fglrx
>
> # Do not edit this file manually
>
> blacklist radeon
>
> alias fglrx fglrx
>
> alias radeon off
>
> alias lbm-radeon off

I made a copy of the file and named it "fglrx-core.bak" and deleted the original "fglrx-core.conf" file.

After rebooting, I immediately noticed that the login field was only on one of my monitors and knew that my desktop was once again extended instead of mirrored. After logging in, I was able to set up my extended desktop and rearrange the monitors as is normally done in the GUI's System Settings>Displays.
"fglrx-core.bak" seems to have been the remnant of fglrx that had remained and continued to blacklist the default radeon driver after upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04.  Especially since I also upgraded to 16.04 from 14.04 without first uninstalling fglrx as is recommended.